# React-Native - KeyboardAvoidingView - Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use the keyboardAvoidingView, to display inputs and used next focus. But, when i click in first input ( print label 1623 - Acidez ), this is hidden. How make show this?

[image]
[image]

```
<ReactNative.View key={this.state.selectedTabIndex}>
                <ReactNative.ScrollView style={{ height: this.props.styles.height - 40 }}>

                    <ReactNative.KeyboardAvoidingView
                        keyboardVerticalOffset={0}

                        behavior="position"
                        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: this.state.size }}
                    >
                        {this.tabs[this.state.selectedTabIndex].render()}
                    </ReactNative.KeyboardAvoidingView>

                </ReactNative.ScrollView>
            </ReactNative.View>
```

Comment: Actually not getting your question. please brief it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you increase 'keyboardVerticalOffset' to bigger value like '100' of KeyboardAvoidingView to some bigger amount it would scroll up from keyboard thus avoiding it.I also spent much time in finding the right solution on internet but finally figure it out myself for 'react-native' version '0.50.4'.I got it working like this

```
<View style={…..}>
      <ScrollView>
         <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={100} behavior={"position"}>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

Comment: Thank you its wok  perfectly as i want

Answer (score 7):

keyboardVerticalOffset should be the distance between the top of the screen and the top of the KeyboardAvoidingView. If you're using flex, that number is going to be different depending on the size of the device you're viewing the app on.

The simplest approach I have found is to simply wrap the whole page with KeyboardAvoidingView. By making it your top-level wrapper, you will never have to worry about the keyboardVerticalOffset.

Experiment with the three behavior options from there until you get something that works.

Answer (score 1):

What works today for me - on android - was..

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        key={2}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={0}
        behavior={"padding"}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          overflow: "hidden",
          height: "100%",
          paddingTop: 0,
          marginTop: 0,
          borderTopWidth: 0,
        }}
        windowSize={1}
        enabled
      >
(...)
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```